# Android: Unable to insert data into SQLite

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

Please have a look at the following code

Code to insert data

```
package com.example.esoftcallmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DatabaseHandler implements DatabaseConnector
{
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private String dbPath = "data//data//com.example.esoftcallmanager.sqllite//esoftDatabase";
    private static Context context;

    private static DatabaseHandler instance;

    private DatabaseHandler(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void createConnection() 
    {

        try
        {
            database = context.openOrCreateDatabase("esoftDatabase", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

            String createDatabaseQuery = "create table BranchNetwork(" +
                    "brID integer primary key autoincrement,"
                    +"city text,"
                    +"streetAddress text,"
                    +"phoneNumber1 text,"
                    +"phoneNumber2 text,"
                    +"email text"
                    +");";

            String dropDatabaseQuery = "drop table BranchNetwork";
            database.execSQL(createDatabaseQuery);


        }
        catch(SQLException sql)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, sql.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void closeConnection() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public static DatabaseHandler getInstance(Context context)
    {
        if(instance==null)
        {
            instance = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public static DatabaseHandler getInstance()
    {
        if(instance==null)
        {
            instance = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        }

        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public String insertData(String city, String streetAddress,String phoneNumber1, String phoneNumber2, String email) 
    {
        String insertQuery = "insert into BranchNetwork ('city','streetAddress','phoneNumber1','phoneNumber2','email') values("+city+","+streetAddress+","+phoneNumber1+","+phoneNumber2+","+email+");";

        try
        {
            database.execSQL(insertQuery);
            return "Data Successfully Inserted";
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Exception: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return "Data Insertion Failed";
        }

    }


}
```

Whenever I try to insert data, I get the following error

```
   02-13 23:39:40.424: E/Database(655): Failure 1 (near "@wewe": syntax error) on 0x2a6128 when preparing 'insert into BranchNetwork ('city','streetAddress','phoneNumber1','phoneNumber2','email') values(asas,asasd,3434,3434,aasa@wewe.com);'.
```

What is wrong here? How can I correct it? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply, you need to wrap your Strings in quotes.

```
"values('"+city+"','"+streetAddress+"'..."
```

However, it is often better to use a parameterized query when working with raw values to prevent [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and other unsavory things:

```
db.rawQuery("insert into Foo (bar) values (?)", new String[] {city});
```

Or use the built-in methods like [`SQLiteDatabase#insert()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29)

Comment: though it works the way, a raw query shouldn't be used to insert data. A raw query should only be the last resort...

Comment: Glad I could help! It's a shame someone else disagreed and gave me a downvote... Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this SQL statement :

```
String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO BranchNetwork ('city','streetAddress','phoneNumber1','phoneNumber2','email') VALUES('"+city+"','"+streetAddress+"','"+phoneNumber1+"','"+phoneNumber2+"','"+email+"');";
```

When I am using this kind of sql statements I have problem with the `'` very often .

You can use `ContentValues` for insert / update / delete too. I prefer it instead of writing SQL statements like that. In your situation you can do this :

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("city", city);
values.put("streetAddress",streetAddress);
values.put("phoneNumber1",phoneNumber1); // and ETC.
//INSERT 
sqliteDb.insert("BranchNetwork", null, values);
```

Comment: Great! Thank you a lot for letting me know another way! +1 from me!

Answer (score 2):

The following will not work:

```
String insertQuery = "insert into BranchNetwork ('city','streetAddress','phoneNumber1','phoneNumber2','email') values("+city+","+streetAddress+","+phoneNumber1+","+phoneNumber2+","+email+");";
```

You shouldn't create your own insert SQL, instead use `ContentValues` and just use something like that to insert:

```
db.insert(TABLENAME, null, cv);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for providing me another approach! +1 from me!